# Attempting to call an Oracle Stored Function that returns a ref cursor to C#

Tags: c#, oracle, function, cursor, return

I have been pulling my hair trying to get a resultset back from an oracle stored function that returns a ref cursor.

Here is the declaration for by Oracle Stored Function:

```
TYPE GetInspectorCursor IS REF CURSOR;
FUNCTION GetInspectorInformation
   (inUserID IN inspectortable.userid%type,
    inPassword IN inspectortable.password%type,
    inCompanyID IN inspectortable.cid%type,
    inSubCompanyID in inspectortable.scid%type,
    outErrorcode OUT NUMBER)
RETURN GetInspectorCursor;
```

Here is my c# program to get the result set:

```
        String connString = "DATA SOURCE=PEOPLE.WORLD;PASSWORD=password;PERSISTSEC CURITY INFO=True;USER ID=userid";


        DataSet ds;
        OracleDataAdapter myAdapter = null;
        Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor refCursor = null;

        OracleConnection myCon = new OracleConnection(connString);

        String commandText = "schema.package.GetInspectorInformation";

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(commandText, myCon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        // inpectorID
        OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter();
        param.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = "JOHN";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        // inspector Password
        OracleParameter param2 = new OracleParameter();
         param2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
         param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
         param2.Value = "12345";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

        // VALUE 1
        OracleParameter param3 = new OracleParameter();
         param3.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
         param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
         param3.Value = "VA1";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

        // VALUE 2
        OracleParameter param4 = new OracleParameter();
         param4.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
         param4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
         param4.Value = "VA2";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);

        // outParam Error Code
        OracleParameter param5 = new OracleParameter();
         param5.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
         param5.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         //param5.IsNullable = true;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param5);


        OracleParameter param6 = new OracleParameter();
         param.ParameterName = "RefCursor";
         param6.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object;
         param6.OracleDbTypeEx = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
         param6.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
         ///param6.IsNullable = false;
         cmd.Parameters.Add(param6);


         myCon.Open();

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        refCursor = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor)cmd.Parameters["RefCursor"].Value;
        myAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter("", myCon);
        ds = new DataSet("testDS");
        myAdapter.Fill(ds, refCursor);

        // Clean up
        cmd.Dispose();
        myCon.Close();
        myCon.Dispose();
```

On myCon.Open() call I get:

```
 ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
 PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETINSPECTORINFORMATION'
 ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Would someone be kind enough to spare a few brain cells and me tell what/which parameter is being passed incorrectly?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to return one via a function, but you can return a REF CURSOR via a procedure. Try this - it's worked for me before on many projects:

First, change the function to a procedure:

```
PROCEDURE GetInspectorInformation
   (inUserID IN inspectortable.userid%type,
    inPassword IN inspectortable.password%type,
    inCompanyID IN inspectortable.cid%type,
    inSubCompanyID in inspectortable.scid%type,
    outErrorcode OUT NUMBER,
    retCursor getInspectorCursor OUT);
```

Then in your C# code, change this...

```
param6.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

... to this...

```
param6.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Then fill the dataset by replacing everything starting with `myCon.Open()` with the following:

```
ds = new DataSet("testDS");
new OracleDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
```

If you have trouble with this, note that whenever I've done this my code had the following differences from what you posted:

- The ref cursor has been the *only* `OUT` parameter
- The ref cursor has been a generic `SYS_REFCURSOR`
- The `adapter.Fill` has been to a data table within the data set (`new OracleDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds.myTableName)`

So you may still need to experiment a bit, but as I said this has worked for me before.

Comment: Yes! Thanks!  In my case however, I need a reference cursor returned via call to a funtion.